# Error After Displaying Test Ads in iOS App Development in Xcode using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ads

I have generated test ads in my app and displayed it whenever the user presses the exit button. But, as the user presses the button the test ad is generated perfectly, but then it is not able to perform segue-way to switch to the main view controller. Any suggestions on how can I solve this issue! I have provided the following code to generate test ads for your reference below. Would appreciate your help!

```
import GoogleMobileAds

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
    let request = GADRequest()
    interstitial.load(request)

}

@IBAction func exitButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    
    if (interstitial.isReady) {
        
      interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
      interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
        
    }
    
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "3to1segue", sender: self)
    
}

func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
  let inter = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
  inter.load(GADRequest())
  return inter
}
```